# Simple Analog Read Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to program some software for my Arduino to read data from an IR fire detector module, I know the module works but I just cannot get the Arduino to read from it and carry out a function correctly. I want it to work like this...

```
const int IRDetector1Input = A2;
const int IRDetector1Output = A1;
const int LEDButton = 3;

void setup(){
pinMode(IRDetector1Input, INPUT);
pinMode(IRDetector1Output, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LEDButton, OUTPUT);

void loop(){   //Problem Point
if analogRead(IRDetectorInput, HIGH); //This is the problem, the code doesn't match with digital or analog write. 
   digitalWrite(LEDButton, HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that I see.

One, is that you are using the `analogRead()` function incorrectly.  When you perform an `analogRead()` the function reads a digital representation of the voltage as seen at the requested pin and returns an integer value (0 to 1023).  Also, this function only takes a single parameter, the pin number.  You are sending the pin number and `HIGH`.  Here is an example of what to do if you wanted to know what the digital representation of the voltage was at that analog pin:

```
int analogValue;
analogValue = analogRead(IRDetector1Input);
```

The second issue is with your `if()` statement.  I believe that you are trying to see if the value received at the pin (where your IR detector is connected) is actually `HIGH`.  First, your `if()` statement would be more correct (but still wrong), like this:

```
if (analogRead(IRDetector1Input) == HIGH)
    digitalWrite(LEDButton, HIGH);
```

The reason that it is still wrong is that `HIGH` is a value that is defined as being the integer number 1, whereas `LOW` is defined as 0. So, you would be comparing the return value of `analogRead()` which could be anywhere from 0 to 1023, to the number 1.

So... how can you fix it?  Well, it's tough to say without knowing how your IR detector module works.  If the detector sends a digital value (a high voltage or a low voltage and not something in between) to your Arduino, use digital functions and a digital pin (i.e. `digitalRead()`).  However, if your IR is actually sending an undetermined voltage, then set an analog threshold and check for it.  You will need to run tests to determine where this threshold should be.  For example:

```
#define ANALOG_IR_THRESHOLD   750  /* Arbitrarily set */

if (analogRead(IRDetector1Input) >= ANALOG_IR_THRESHOLD)
{
    digitalWrite(LEDButton, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The IR detector just either sends a HIGH or LOW signal and the datasheet says its a 0 or a 1. I can theoretically add the module to a digital pin, so could I just substitute the analogRead for digitalRead?

Comment: You should be able to use `if (digitalRead(IRdetector1Input) == HIGH)`.  And (according to the Arduino website), you should be able to use digitalRead on an analog pin as well... I've never tried it though.